# start a service with Alarmmanager at specific date and time and Repeating

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I want to create reminder app

I have searched a lot of places but couldnt find a clean sequential explanation of how to start a service (or if thats not possible then an activity) at a specific time daily using the AlarmManager?

i want start service at specific date and time and for example Six months after that date start the service again And continue this cycle

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileList.this, BroadcastedReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(ProfileList.this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000, pintent);
```

i tried this code to activate the alarm at 2018-02/12 9:00... this is Works on this date but i have problem to repeating after for example six month...How do I change the codes to be start service every six months?

NOTE: Dates are stored in the database And they will be called from there

Comment: 6 months is too long time for repeating alarm. I am not saying that it's not possible but probably user will uninstall app in between that time. you can go with another better approach.

Comment: This app is not for users and will only use one person

Comment: [Best practice](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to use job scheduler or firebase dispatcher for your requirement

refer this links
https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

Comment: i cant use firebase , Because this service is banned for my country I want to use the alarms

Comment: what about job scheduler

Comment: A program to remind you when to switch the filter water purifier

Comment: Can I run job scheduler on a specific date?

Comment: yes.you can create a periodic job with an interval of 6 months  using  .setperiodic.. just refer some examples you will understand

Comment: thank you,So I should use job scheduler This is better than Alarmmanager

Comment: yes, it is the new method  so it has some advantages over the alarm manager like checking the internet connection, check device is on charging  etc

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class AddService extends Service
    {
        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           //Your Logic
            stopSelf();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000*60*60),
                    PendingIntent.getService(this,0,new Intent(this,AddService.class),0));
        }
    }

// Here your service will call every 1 hour, you can change time according to that
```

Comment: thank you, what is stopSelf() function? ,sorry i'm beginner can you send me full code with MainActivity and service and mainfest...

Comment: stopself is used to end the service

Comment: it will stop and then again starts after 1 hour @MarGin

Comment: In manifest  <service android:name=".services.AddService"/>  and in mainactivity startService(new Intent(this, AddService.class));

Comment: so where i can set specific date?

Comment: InterstitialAd is null??